# error ::sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: CountVectorizer - Vocabulary wasn't fitted

Tags: python, scikit-learn

How do I solve the error here in `vectorizor.tranform(fd_norm)`?

```
encoder = LabelEncoder()
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
lis=[description]
lis1=[name_predict]
lis2=[text_predict]
lis_df=pd.DataFrame(lis,columns=['description'])
lis1_df=pd.DataFrame(lis1,columns=['name'])
lis2_df=pd.DataFrame(lis2,columns=['text'])
pred_df=pd.concat([lis_df,lis1_df,lis2_df],axis=1)
fd=pred_df.iloc[ : , : ].values    
fd_norm=[normalize_text(s) for s in fd]
predV=vectorizer.transform(fd_norm)
fname='gender_predictor.sav'
model=pickle.load(open(fname,'rb'))
fresnel=model.predict(predV)
fresnel_label=encoder.inverse_transform(fresnel)
self.gender.setText(fresnel_label)
```

the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "the_linking.py", line 162, in predict
    predV=self._vectorizer.transform(fd_norm)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 890, in transform
    self._check_vocabulary()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 278, in _check_vocabulary
    check_is_fitted(self, 'vocabulary_', msg=msg),
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 690, in check_is_fitted
    raise _NotFittedError(msg % {'name': type(estimator).__name__})
sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: CountVectorizer - Vocabulary wasn't fitted.
```

Comment: A title that is only an error message, and the content of the question is just a code is not a good question, I recommend reading [ask]

Comment: that problem has nothing to do with PyQt but with sklearn.

Comment: yaa i am trying to get the text from textEdit widget and vectorize it but its showing this error

Comment: What is the textedit ?, I see that the problem is caused before doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before calling `transform()`, you must call `fit()` or `fit_transform()` once, so that the model can learn the frequencies of data.
Try:

```
predV=vectorizer.fit_transform(fd_norm)
```

Same goes for **encoder**. I think you have previously transformed the data and then trained the model. But from there, you only saved the `model`, but not vectorizer. You need to save both `vectorizer` and `encoder` when you are saving the model, to be able to use them again. Load them the same way as you are doing for model and use them (without calling `fit()` in this case.)

Comment: i have already fitted the model and pickled it to a .sav file . i am then loading it to predict in the above code